# How to send stream of WAV audio to diaglogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I have a json with a field that contains a Aduio(WAV). Now I want to send it to dialogflow.

As shown in the code, after decoding the data, i want to send it directly to dialogflow instead of saving that in file and then passing it to dialogflow.

```py
# instead of audio_file_path int the below method, i want to pass a variable that contains audio data

def detect_intent_stream(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                         language_code):   
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    audio_encoding = dialogflow.enums.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16
    sample_rate_hertz = 16000

    session_path = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session_path))

    def request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path):
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

        # The first request contains the configuration.
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=session_path, query_input=query_input)

        # Here we are reading small chunks of audio data from a local
        # audio file.  In practice these chunks should come from
        # an audio input device.
        with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
            while True:
                chunk = audio_file.read(4096)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                # The later requests contains audio data.
                yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
                    input_audio=chunk)

    audio_config = dialogflow.types.InputAudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=audio_encoding, language_code=language_code,
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate_hertz)

    requests = request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path)
    responses = session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)

    print('=' * 20)
    for response in responses:
        print('Intermediate transcript: "{}".'.format(
                response.recognition_result.transcript))

    # Note: The result from the last response is the final transcript along
    # with the detected content.
    query_result = response.query_result

    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(query_result.fulfillment_text))

# ----------------------------------------------------

data = request.json["data"]  # this contain Audio(WAV) in base64 format

decoded = base64.b64decode(audio)  # decoding base64

# I want this like I am passing "decoded" variable that contains audio data in WAV format instead of audio file path
detect_intent_stream('my_project_id','my_session_id', decoded,'language_code') 

f = open('new.wav', 'wb').write(decoded) # writing the decoded data into file
```

Comment: "As shown in the code" -- there is nothing about `dialogflow` in the code. Please, update your question. What have you tried to actually pass data directly?

Comment: done. please check

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that the WAV data you are receiving is in the proper format and matches the sample rate (typically 44100) and correct number of audio channels (Dialogflow uses only mono, or single channel, audio). In the code they provide they set an audio_encoding variable, and an input audio config, look into those.

Next, you have a string of WAV data, but StreamingDetectIntentRequest accepts bytes, so instead of converting your base64 into a string, I would convert it into a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray)

Next, instead of yielding audio chunks from an audio file, yield chunks from the byte array.

```
    def request_generator(audio_config, byte_array):
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

        # The first request contains the configuration.
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=session_path, query_input=query_input) 

        for chunk in range(44, len(byte_array), 4096): # Start at position 44 to discard the wav header
            yield  dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
                input_audio=bytes(chunk))
```